# Cannot display traffic with Osmdroid map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is there any methods for displaying traffic in Osmdroid lib? I suppose there is no easy way as google's setTrafficEnabled();

Comment: OSM doesn't have traffic information available. But it you have access to a third-party service providing this information then it should be possible to show it via osmdroid.

Answer (score 1):

OSM doesn't have traffic information available. But it you have access to a third-party service providing this information then it should be possible to show it via osmdroid.